# how to get the url from the event listener in cordova inapp browser event? and close it after reaching a specific url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Here is my code of closing the in app browser after reaching a specific URL in ionic version 1 (BTW i am new to ionic & angularjs). Here my problem is the event on "loadstart" is MouseEvent i couldn't find any url in the object i am getting undefined error on console.log(event.url) . I tried with Loadstop and exit too in the event listener.

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  function onDeviceReady() {

      function onExit(event) {

          var urlSuccessPage = "https://tick.com/s";
          alert(event);
          alert(event.url);

          console.log(event.url);
          console.log(event);
          if (event.url == urlSuccessPage) {

              inAppBrowser.close();
          }
      }

      var inAppBrowser = window.open("https://tick.com", "_blank", "location=yes");

 inAppBrowser.addEventListener('loadstart', onExit(event));


  }
```

Comment: hello,
when you are calling to 
 inAppBrowser.addEventListener('loadstart', onExit(event));
then i think onExit(event ) will  not be fire because of this function is not in the javascript scope

Comment: make onExit(event) function outside the deviceready, then it will work

Comment: onExit(event) is working fine but the event raised here is MouseEvent . url is undefined in the MouseEvent.

Comment: try to get thing, by using event.target

Comment: @KunvarSingh event.target gets the button which is used to fire

Answer (score 0):

It worked with the Themeable Cordova browser plugin. Here is the link of that plugin of ionic https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

```
$scope.opens = function () {

var tb =   cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open('https://tick.com', '_blank', {
      statusbar: {
          color: '#ffffffff'
      },
      toolbar: {
          height: 44,
          color: '#f0f0f0ff'
      },
      title: {
          color: '#003264ff',
          showPageTitle: true
      },
      backButton: {
          image: 'back',
          imagePressed: 'back_pressed',
          align: 'left',
          event: 'backPressed'
      },
      forwardButton: {
          image: 'forward',
          imagePressed: 'forward_pressed',
          align: 'left',
          event: 'forwardPressed'
      },
      closeButton: {
          image: 'close',
          imagePressed: 'close_pressed',
          align: 'left',
          event: 'closePressed'
      },
      customButtons: [
          {
              image: 'share',
              imagePressed: 'share_pressed',
              align: 'right',
              event: 'sharePressed'
          }
      ],
      menu: {
          image: 'menu',
          imagePressed: 'menu_pressed',
          title: 'Test',
          cancel: 'Cancel',
          align: 'right',
          items: [
              {
                  event: 'helloPressed',
                  label: 'Hello World!'
              },
              {
                  event: 'testPressed',
                  label: 'Test!'
              }
          ]
      },
      backButtonCanClose: true
  }).addEventListener('backPressed', function (e) {
      alert('back pressed');
  }).addEventListener('helloPressed', function (e) {
      alert('Hello pressed');
     // ThemeableBrowser.run('backPressed');
     // cordova.ThemeableBrowser.run("logoClick");
  }).addEventListener('sharePressed', function (e) {
      alert(e.url);
  }).addEventListener('loadstart', function (e) {
      var urlSuccessPage = "https://tick.com/s";


      var ss = "https://www.tick/b";



      if (e.url == urlSuccessPage) {


          tb.close();


      }
      if (e.url == ss) {

          tb.close();

      }

  }).addEventListener('loadstop', function (e) {

  });
}
```